# DAX Measure for Cancellations (Cancel Date vs. Book Date)

Tags: dax

I have a 'Reservations' table that looks like this;

| Reservation ID | Book Date | Status | Cancel Date | Booking Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-01-01 | Active |  | 1 |
| 5678 | 2021-01-01 | Active |  | 1 |
| 9101 | 2021-01-01 | Cancelled | 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| 1121 | 2021-01-02 | Cancelled | 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 3141 | 2021-01-02 | Active |  | 1 |

The 'Book Date' column is in an active relationship with a Calendar table via. the Date column. Current measures are like this;

```
Gross Bookings:SUM(Booking Flag)
Cancellations:CALCULATE([Gross Bookings],'Reservations'[Status]="Cancelled")
Net Bookings:[Gross Bookings]-[Cancellations]
```

I want to be able to produce a table like this;

| Date | Gross Bookings | Cancellations | Net Bookings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 | 1 | -1 |

But what I am getting looks like this, as the 'Cancel Date' is not being understood in the Measures;

| Date | Gross Bookings | Cancellations | Net Bookings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

How can I use DAX to shift my Cancellation Measure so it corresponds to the correct Cancel Date whilst still respecting my Date relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is solved now, by creating an Inactive Relationship between 'Cancel Date' and the Calendar Date table, then using this DAX for the Cancellation measure;

```
CALCULATE([Gross Bookings],'Reservations'[Status]="Cancelled",USERELATIONSHIP('Reservations'[Cancel Date],'Calendar'[Date]))
```

This seems to be doing the expected output, to be tested further. Worth noting I had to populate book date in the Cancel Date nulls, to create the relationship.